# Is it a good idea to have database queries inside a data class?

Tags: oop

If I put database queries in a class that is representing a real world object, does that violate the design rule that entities must not have access to data sources?

Here is an example

```
class User
{
  public function register
  {
  }

  private function save_user_data()
  {
    // database queries here, either in AR or ORM
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a design rule that states "entities must not have access to data sources", and you create an entity that has access to its data source, then I would say the rule has been violated. Didn't you mean to ask if such thing is a good idea?

Comment: I may have meant it that way...hm...but if I use ORM that means that the ORM library do the queries for me. Is putting ORM methods in that class the same as having queries in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote Steve McConnell (Code Complete [1,2]):

> Sofware's Primary Technical Imperative is managing complexity.

If you're writing a large scale app, in the long run it will reduce complexity to abstract data access. If you're writing a small to medium size app, it may make more sense to do your data access within the object itself, so long as you are clear and consistent with it.

Reduce complexity in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that the responsibility of saving the class should be with itself, however the actual code to perform the save to the database should go into a class in a data access layer.

Answer (score 0):

Well quite clearly yes. But the real question is does this rule matter? Depends, I suppose.

Personally, I just use an ORM to generate all this stuff for me. LLBLGen.